# Invoke a Java class present in an ear from a shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have a class dealerProfile.class in CompanyUS.ear which is deployed in the server. I wrote a simple shell script to invoke the class 'dealerProfile.class'
'com.download.DealerProfile' is the package the class is in

`code dealerProfile.sh: java com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer`

I am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:677)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
Could not find the main class: com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer.  Program will exit.
```

I understand that I need to set class path to the class file location in .ear

but I dont know how to do it.

My first time posting a question so please excuse if it looks amatuer.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time to read the thread

Answer (score 1):

EAR files are meant for deployment on a server like JBoss or similar. It is usual that it contains jar files and/or web archives (WAR files). Java runtime will not execute an EAR file as it will do for a Jar file (using java -jar) so you cannot use the command line for running a java executable. You should drop it into an application server or package your classes in a Jar file even allowing you to nest jar files in one another.

The command to run your class in a jar will look like:

```
java -jar CompanyUS.jar com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I deployed the ear file in Application server and my jar file in the .ear is with the name 'WebAMSEJB.jar' and I ran the command 'java -jar WebAMSEJB.jar com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer'  which is throwing me this error 'Unable to access jarfile WebAMSEJB.jar' Thanks again for taking time, let me know what should I be doing

Comment: when you say 'package your classes in a Jar file even allowing you to nest jar files in one another.' Can you explain this is details if not a lot to ask for

Comment: Unless the jarfile is in the current working directory, you will need to specify the full path to it on the java command line: "java -jar /some/path/to/a/jarfile.jar com.your.main.ClassName"

Comment: As jdv points, the -jar option should include the route to the jar file. For example 'java -jar ./jboss/standalone/deployments/CompanyUs/WebAMSEJB.jar com.download.DealerProfile.testShellDealer'. Be sure thart the jar file is accesible and has right permissions.